# I am not able to get .Click() intellisense in C# visual studio for selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests

Here is my code. form of simple login and I want to **click on cant access your account**, in C# using visual studio 13 ,test script selenium. thanks in advance.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Text;
 using OpenQA.Selenium;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
 using System.Threading;

 namespace test1
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
             driver.Url = "http://mysite/Account/Login";
             driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Can't access your account?")).
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error(s)?

Comment: var links = driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Can't access your account?")).Click();       when i am typing this i am getting error in . Click()

Comment: can you show html source ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Click()` method available on the array of web elements. Replace:

```
driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Can't access your account?")).Click();
```

with:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Can't access your account?")).Click();
```

watch the "s".

Comment: thank you. error is now gone, but that link is not getting clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)         
{             
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));             
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://mysite/Account/Login");             
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Can't access your account?")).Click();         
}
```